# Django. Display of an HTML element in the ckeditor editor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

There is a task

in ckeditor when adding an HTML div in the editor, how can I display the area (that the tag is "added" in this place)?

```
<div data-content="menu" data-id="test-menu" data-type="extra">div-menu</div>
```

Now I have it displayed like this
[image]

I want it to look something like this
[image]

How can this be done in Django? (so that styles are not applied to HTML, but only work in the editor)

to insert custom HTML I wrote my plugin. Here is the code snippet that inserts the desired HTML

```
html_menu = '<div data-type=\"extra\" data-content=\"menu\" data-id=\"'+menu+'\">div-menu</div>'
editor.insertHtml(html_menu)
```